# Call method on certain distance between nodes in Spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a game where enemies follow player. I tried enumerating all enemy nodes and calculating distance to a player. I did all this in `Update` function. By doing so I have a huge FPS drop and almost 100% CPU usage. Is there any other way I can achieve the same behavior?

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"enemy" usingBlock:^(SKNode * _Nonnull node, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if(SDistanceBetweenPoints(self.player.position, node.position)<120)
        {
            if((![[node.userData objectForKey:@"move"] boolValue])&&
              ((SDistanceBetweenPoints(self.player.position, node.position)>45)))
            {
                [self findPathFor:node To:self.player.position];
            }
            else if (round(SDistanceBetweenPoints(self.player.position, node.position) <= 32.01) &&
                    (![node hasActions]) &&
                    (![[self.player.userData objectForKey:@"move"] boolValue]))
            {
                [self thisNode:node attack:self.player];
            }

            [self update:node WithDeltaTime:deltaTime];
        }
}];
```

**EDIT**: When I'm enumerating enemies from `self`, maybe it's taking so much time, because I have lots and lots of nodes in `self`. Maybe it would be better to create like a separate *self thingy* for enemies?

**EDIT2**: I tried adding all enemies to an array and used for loop instead of enumerating. And now I get steady 60 fps and ±40% CPU usage.

```
for (SKNode *node in self.enemiesArray) {
    [self update:node WithDeltaTime:deltaTime];
}

SKAction *enemiesFollow = [SKAction runBlock:^{

    for(SKNode *node in self.enemiesArray){
       [...]
    }

}];

SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5];

if(![self actionForKey:@"enemyFollow"]){
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, enemiesFollow]] withKey:@"enemyFollow"];
}
```

Is it the right way of doing this?

Comment: Show the code you are using.

Comment: try your app in device sometimes simulator shows 100% cpu usage and game goes hang.

Comment: Well, it's 100% on device. :/ (iPhone5)

Comment: The update function is getting called too frequently. I think you might not need to calculate the distance everytime the update function is called. Instead, you can update the distance between the nodes after some time interval (say 0.25 seconds)

Comment: Another solution you could explore is let all the enemy nodes repeatedly run an SKAction, that moves the enemy self node the by a certain distance. The distance to move will be distance between self (enemy node) and the player.

Comment: TheAppMentor is correct; this "AI" type behaviour doesn't need calling every frame.  Also you are calling `SDistanceBetweenPoints` 3 times.  The value it returns won't change, so store its value in a variable.  You are also calling some sort of custom `update` method as well; why is that?

Comment: That custom update method is used to walk node through the path (if there's one).

Comment: Isn't there some sort of rule or like a restriction to add for node? On the meantime I'm going to try not to call that on every frame.

Comment: As others have said using an array instead of enumerating the node tree should drastically improve performance. You should also try adding a counter and run your potentially expensive find path algorithm/AI Logic less often. You should also turn your Enemy into a custom class with properties instead of always fetching values from the UserData dictionary. Regarding your second edit, you should not create and run SKActions every frame like that. You should perform real-time calculations manually if you want to get the best performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a different approach would serve you much better.

Instead of calculating the distance between the player and every node every update, use the collisions frame work which should calculate much faster.

Add a circle node with a transparent color (UIColor with the alpha 0)to the player that has a radius of how far away you want something to happen when the enemies get that close. When an enemy collides with the circle run your code.

Comment: Wow! That's really smart. But you see, i'm kind of afraid of doing this because I don't need any physics collisions (like node pushing one another).

Comment: you can use contact bit masks and collision bit masks so that the nodes don't bump into each other but your still notified when they come into contact

Comment: Okay, but what about player walking. Player node walks by tapping screen, and I would tap that circle instead of floor.

Comment: make that circles zPosition negative